# How can I update my redux state correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing a problem, I am new to Redux, and I am just playing around with it, So I have a problem, I created a data json file, I get the data from it in my reducer, and everything works fine, here is my reducer :

```
import update from "immutability-helper";

import data from "../../../../data";

export default function notificationsReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "NOTIFICATIONS_EDIT_TO_FOLLOW":
      return update(state, {
        [action.id]: {
          follwing: { $set: false }
        }
      });
      break;
    case "NOTIFICATIONS_EDIT_TO_UNFOLLOW":
      return [];
      break;
    default:
      return data.notifications;
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the default part, I return data.notififications, this causes a probleme of course, because the data in the json file does not change, the state does.

When I work on my component and click 'follow' and 'unfollow' and stuffs everything looks fine, but When I click somewhere else outside the component, others actions got dispatched, ( others for different purposes ) and the default part get executed again, so when I open my notifications again all changes I made are gone.

That's my problem, if any explanation from me is needed just ask and I will edit my question.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you're saying in the `default:` case you just want to preserve the existing state? Rather than resetting to the initial `data.notifications` values? Then you should just `return state;` instead of `return data.notifications;` in the `default:` case

Comment: @Jayce444 Well you're right, but it is not working, because When I get my notifications for the first time the state is empty. So ?

Comment: ok well that's a different problem, as in when you refresh the page or something it loads the initial state from the JSON and the new notifications are now gone?

Comment: I have a buttons, when I click on it my notifications container get displayed, and then I can play with my notifications and everything is cool, but I click in that button to hide the container and click again to show it, that's when I see that my initial state is loaded directly from the json, which is normal but I dont know how to do better solution, Understood Sir ?

Comment: If not understood I will edit my post with some images

Comment: Hmm that's really weird, hiding/showing components shouldn't affect the Redux store, it persists regardless of what's being rendered. Can you show how you're building the store and passing it into the provider, as well as what's happening when you hide the container. The hiding of the container shouldn't have any affect on this reducer's values.

Comment: Now, Actually it is logical, because that hide and show click has an action in it, but that action changes something different than the notifications, so what I think is when I lauch that action, all my reducers listen to it, and when it comes to my notifications reducers, the actions TYPE dispatched are different than the ones on my notification actions types, so it goes to the default

Comment: yup, that'll be it. When an action is dispatched, EVERY reducer hears it. That's why returning the existing state is necessary for all the reducers' default cases.

Comment: But When I first time return the existing state, it is empty! my notifications won't be displayed, and many errors will appear, for example in my single notification I have a text displayed notification.username, if the state is empty, I will get an error

Comment: right but you need to add the `data` as the default value to the state parameter, like so: `export default function notificationsReducer(state = data, action) {...}`

Comment: Jayce444 : It worked thanks, Can you rewrite your last comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapping from the comments:

In your default case (for all reducers), you need to return the current state of your reducer so that unrelated actions don't interfere with their values:

```
default:
  return state;
```

You also (if needed) have to set up the initial value of your reducer, in this case the notifications from the data JSON file:

```
export default function notificationsReducer(state = data, action) {...}
```